# Matrix / Low Variables Database Error

Tags: matrix, low-variables, database-error

I am getting the following Database error, which prevents me from even accessing the low variables module screen...

Low Variables - 2.5.0
Matrix - 2.6

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'var_id' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT row_id, col_id_74, col_id_75 FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE var_id
>   = 1 ORDER BY row_order ASC
>
> Filename:
>   /path/to/sitedomain.com/_third_party/matrix/ft.matrix.php
>
> Line Number: 3041

I have searched all the posts on it and nothing has yet solved my problem. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Check out the solutions offered in this thread and see if that helps: https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low_variables_matrix_database_error

Comment: Yup I already tried that. It worked AT FIRST but as soon as I added a new variable it caused the error again. Running through the same solution again at that point did not solve the problem.